# Show the limit is $1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$\lim_{q \to \infty} \frac{x^q - y^q}{x^q + y^q} = 1$ for $x \gt y$ and $x,y \gt 0$.

I've been trying this for a while and still don't get it. We have the indeterminate form so we do L'Hopital, but that was go on infinitely.

Hints?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082115/limit-of-function-at-infinity-lim-n-to-infty-fracan-bnanbn https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577788/lim-n-to-infty-an-bn-over-anbn

Answer (score 4):

Hint. Divide top and bottom by $x^q$.

Answer (score 3):

By squeeze theorem, we have

$$\frac{x^q-2y^q}{x^q}<\frac{x^q-y^q}{x^q+y^q}<\frac{x^q-y^q}{x^q}$$

$$1-2\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^q<\frac{x^q-y^q}{x^q+y^q}<1-\left(\frac yx\right)^q$$

$$\lim_{q\to\infty}1-2\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^q<\lim_{q\to\infty}\frac{x^q-y^q}{x^q+y^q}<\lim_{q\to\infty}1-\left(\frac yx\right)^q$$

$$1<\lim_{q\to\infty}\frac{x^q-y^q}{x^q+y^q}<1$$

Answer (score 2):

Someone else has already given a strong hint, so I will not reiterate. Instead I will explain why you should use that method given.

So here is another hint:

The way you handle limits involving fractions is to factor out the dominant term from the numerator and denominator such that they cancel out. The dominant term in this case is $x^q$.