# Stuck with this limit of a sum: $\lim _{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{a^{n}-b^{n}}{a^{n}+b^{n}}\right)$.

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, summation

Here's the limit: $$\lim _{n \to \infty}  \left(\frac{a^{n}-b^{n}}{a^{n}+b^{n}}\right)$$

The conditions are $b>0$ and $a>0$.

I tried this with the case that $a>b$:

$$\lim _{n \to \infty}  \left(\frac{1-\frac{b^{n}}{a^{n}}}{1+\frac{b^{n}}{a^{n}}}\right)$$

It gives me the result $1$.

But, in the case of $b>a$, I don't find a solution. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577788/lim-n-to-infty-an-bn-over-anbn https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082115/limit-of-function-at-infinity-lim-n-to-infty-fracan-bnanbn https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2009240/show-the-limit-is-1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $b > a$, divide both the numerator and denominator by $b^n$ to get:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{a^n}{b^n}-1}{\frac{a^n}{b^n}+1}=\frac{-1}{1}=-1$$

Comment: oh im so dumb how didn't i think abt it omg :'( thanks dude

Comment: @AymanErroutabi No problem! Also, I don't think you are dumb because you did a good job with the other case!

Comment: Im pretty sure this is wrong

Comment: @Euler_Salter Why so? When $a < b$, we have that $\frac{a^n}{b^n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ and thus the limit is just $\frac{0-1}{0+1}$.

Comment: @AymanErroutabi No, I meant to divide the numerator and denominnator of the original fraction $\frac{a^n-b^n}{a^n+b^n}$ by $b^n$

Comment: Im pretty sure this is right, apologies

Comment: oh thats right too .when u divide the second result i mentioned by $\frac{b^{n}}{a^{n}}$ u ll get the same equation u wrote .. damn maths are so fascinating and thanks btw

Comment: @AymanErroutabi I can definitely feel you.

Comment: @Simple Art yeah the only thing that can be simple and complicated same time .

Answer (score 4):

Hint: In case of $b>a$ you divide by $b^n$
In case of $a=b$ it is simply zero.

Comment: yeah u re absolutly right man im exhausted couldnt even think abt it lol thank you